# Chart.js 2.7.0 How to add Horizontal scrollbar dynamically, and then remove it

Tags: javascript, css, html, chart.js2

[EDIT] Just look at my answer to learn how to scroll (or not scroll, depending upon bar width), and to scroll with a locked y-axis, and to have text in your bars, but have them flip vertically when needed.[END EDIT]

An accepted solution for adding horizontal scrolling, is to do the following:

Put the canvas in a fixed size div. Then, have that div inside a container that allows scrolling.

OK, that's great.  But until I really *need* scrolling, I'd like the canvas to take up 100% of the Height and Width of the window.  Here's what I mean:

For example, here's the original suggestion:

```
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0;">
<div id="canvas-wrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;">
<div id="canvas-holder" style="height: 100%; width: 500px;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmpxgufu/152/

When you look at this jsfiddle, you can see that the wrapper has overflow-x set to scroll, and the fixed sized div is set to (randomly) 500px.  So, in the jsfiddle, if you adjust the output window size to less than 500 px, it will add the scrollbar (of course!), but when the window size is greater than 500px, I just get blank space to the right of the chart.  Yuck.

So, I was trying something, how about if I have some event (and here I used the animation, onComplete event), adjust it for us.  I figured (randomly), that if the bar width got below 14, I could turn on scrolling:

```
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0;">
<div id="canvas-wrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
<div id="canvas-holder" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmpxgufu/154/

The problem with this is that once I switch from no scrolling, to scrolling, the animation event stops firing (where this thing used to fire for every pixel I moved the window).  So I can't set it back to no scrolling, once I turn on scrolling.

If that event always fired, in the instance of the bar being greater than 14, I could set it back to no scrolling.

How do other people do this?  I can't be the only one that doesn't want a fixed with chart - always!

Thanks.

Comment: I've ditched trying to do it in the Animation OnComplete and am using a combination of a global width variable, and the onLoad and onResize events.  I still have some work to do on maintaining a visible y-axis, but once I'm complete I will post my full solution that includes text shifting vertical (when it needs to), and scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For people that want to know:

- how to add scrolling and scroll horizontally a chart.js chart
- and to have it dynamically appear at a certain bar width (in this instance), otherwise there is no scrolling (it fits to window).
- and to have the scrolling with a y-axis that doesn't disappear the second you start scrolling (a locked y-axis).
- and to have text centered in your bar
- and this text flips vertically when the bar reaches a certain width

well ... here's some code to look at!

```
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0;">
<div id="chartWrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
   <div id="canvas-wrapper" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;">
      <div id="canvas-holder" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
      <canvas id="myChart" style="background-Color: white"></canvas>
      </div>
   </div>
   <canvas id="myChartAxis" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; pointer-events: none; height: 100%; width: 0px; background-Color: white"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmpxgufu/159/

(one caveat: I'm not sure why, but when I posted my code that was working with the chart.js libraries that I linked to locally while developing, and I tested locally, was giving me all types of errors when put into jsfiddle.  So this code was quickly modified to work -- so it's probably not perfect, but will give you ideas)

Comment: Woah, wait a minute here.  How would/could I ever get a down-vote here.  I have provided valuable info for something that people want to know (re: chart.js).  This is ridiculous.  How about some type of explanation, because this is ridiculous.

Comment: this is simply not working. no scroll barupon resizing, but chart is shrinking.